# error acessing and editing a Qmap from inside a OpenMP loop

Tags: c++, qt, openmp, qmap, qvector

I am doing a loop for with openmp in c++ to feed some values inside a QMAP from a QVector and in some computers it says "program stopped to work" but in some computers it works.

I saw that Qmap is not thread safe however I need a container with tags (because of that I use a Qmap) to input the results from an inside calculation and use it later in a serial part of the code.

an example of my code is as follows: Being `mystringlist` a `QString`, `themaps` is a `QMap<QString, QMap<int, QVector<float>>>` and `myvector` a `QVector<float>`.

```
#pragma omp parallel for  schedule(static) num_threads(std::thread::hardware_concurrency())
 for (int i = 0; i < numb_of_iter; i++) 
{
   for each (auto var in mystringlist)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
       {
           themaps[var][i] << std::log10(j+1) + myvector[i]; 
       }
    }
}
```

in serial mode this code works, however in a parallel block sometimes it crashes. So my idea is if there is a method to allow all threads to acess this variable themaps so it wont crash because they wont try to write in the same memory space, each one has its own `i` so they should be able to do that. I do not know another option to do that because I need to use this variable `themaps` later on the code.

Comment: If it is not thread safe, then you should not attempt to use it in parallel. Basically, one of the calls may induce some memory reallocation in one of the Qmap objects and leave another thread with an invalid pointer. Looping on `var` first then `i` may help as the inner Qmap objects will be accessed by one thread at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sane solution: Protect your shared variables via a [mutex](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmutex.html). You of course pay a performance penalty for that, which is only acceptable if the calculation of the new value takes much longer than the insertion into your data structure.

The bold solution: Preallocate all fields so that the data structure doesn't change because of the insertions.

You'd need to consider two effects:

1. If you access a `QMap` key that doesn't exist, a new field will be created. The map will detach. This will change the internal data layout.
2. If you access the map with a non-const method, the map will detach, too, if you have more than one reference to it (Qt's copy-on-write idiom).

For `QVector`, that's simple with `QVector::resize(n)`. After this, you can set any field value within [0..n-1] as long as no one else reads or writes to that field at the same time.

`QMap` is a different beast. Avoid, if possible.
(Just a hint: Only the iterators guarantee not to return a **copy** of the item.)